# Using jQuery to listen for an AJAX load that is not loaded using jQuery.AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, plugins, jquery-plugins

Okay, have a bit of a tricky one (for me anyway, i'm pretty rubbish at jQuery/JavaScript).

I'm pulling in data using standard AJAX (ie, NOT using a framework like jQuery or whatnot... there is a reason for it)

However, I then need to load up a jQuery script as soon as the page has been loaded in. So, here is the question, how do I bind the script once the DOM has been updated? I have been using Ariel Fleser's *listen* plugin (http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jquerylisten.html) for picking up on events such as clicks which works a treat, but I can't see how this can be used to *listen* for a load event.

Any ideas? I'm pretty stumped on this one!!

Comment: As Matt asked below, "what's the reason for not using the AJAX functionality provided in jQuery?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with:

```
yourXMLHTTPRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState == 4) {
      doJQueryStuff();
  }
}
```

Also, what's the reason for not using the AJAX functionality provided in jQuery?

As an aside, it looks like that plugin you mention just replicates the functionality given by the [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live) and [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) methods brought into jQuery in 1.4

Comment: Duh, I completely didn't actually think of that! Probably because I am feeling mega ill! Worked a treat though cheers for the quick response!

Reason for not using the jQuery AJAX bits is just out of preference and that it is for a large system. I did look into it but found it not quite suitable for what was required.

Comment: Im having the same issue but for a off the self solution, how do I find out what the "yourXMLHTTPRequest" is? Cant really dive into the code that has been written but just want to fire a method once the call has been made

Answer (score 1):

In order to parse javascript loaded via ajax, you'll need to use eval(). Although, as far as these things go, a lot of coders consider eval() to be, um, evil... ([a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil), [another link](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx)).

Regardless of the right and wrong of eval, [this thread](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=138830) on webdeveloper should get you a lot of the way towards a solution.

Comment: That's pretty interesting stuff, can't say i'm particulary good at javascript to be honest!. I have managed to get it doing what I need for now though